# Creating Table on Amazon Athena for Map Attributes

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-athena

I am trying to get all attributes from a JSON file originated on Amazon DynamoDB. Right now I sending the files to an Amazon S3 bucket and reading it with Amazon Athena. This is an example from a JSON file,

```
    {
  "Items": [
    {
      "payload": {
        "phase": "T",
        "tms_event": "2017-03-16 18:19:50",
        "id_UM": 0,
        "num_severity_level": 0,
        "event_value": 1,
        "int_status": 0
      },
      "deviceId": 6,
      "tms_event": "2017-03-16 18:19:50"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looking to get deviceId, tms_event, phase, id_UM and event_value on separate fields. This is the table that I have but it doesnt separate the fields,

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.iot_table (
  `Items` ARRAY<
    STRUCT<
      `payload`: STRUCT<`phase`: string, `tms_event`: string, `id_UM`: int, `num_severity_level`: int, `event_value`: int, `int_status`: int>,
      `deviceId`: int,
      `tms_event`: string
    >
  >
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://iot-logging/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false')
```

Thanks

Comment: What is it, that you are missing? The table structure is matching your JSON, so what do you mean by "it doesnt separate the fields"?

Comment: When I run the query, the payload attribute displays on one field all values in JSON format, I will like to get each value in his own field. Perhaps is a issue with the query that I am running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are describing lies within the query you are executing. If you are just running a `select *`, the result is a combined JSON.

To select the elements as single columns you need to select them individually:

```
select item.deviceId,item.tms_event, item.payload.phase, 
       item.payload.id_UM, item.payload.event_value
from iot_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(iot_table.Items) AS t (item);
```

The cross join is needed due to the fact, that your first element is an array and can contain multiple Items.